# How to make an ajax call on submit button of a webform?

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-webform, submit-button

These are my code, I have done the form alter in template.php.
Please advice me ! I created a webform by webform module.My aim is to submit the form without the page load.

My code follows here:

```
   function business_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_7') { 
        $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'business_webform_js_submit',
        'wrapper' => 'webform-client-form-7',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    );
   }

   function business_webform_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
       $sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'];
      if ($sid) {
        $node = node_load($form_state['values']['details']['nid']);
        $confirmation = array(
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => check_markup($node->webform['confirmation'], $node-   >webform['confirmation_format'], '', TRUE),
        );
      return $confirmation;
     }
     else {
       return $form;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code. The name of the `#ajax['callback']` function is different than the actual function.
You might want to rename the function:

```
function business_webform_js_submit($form, $form_state)
```

And it should work.

Comment: Oh ! I am so sorry !! I pasted the code wrongly here, I tried by giving the correct function names, but still the page loads. Thanks for pointing my mistake.